# C# generic parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, generics

Let's say I have some generic `interface IMyInterface<TParameter1, TParameter2>`.

*Now, if I'm writing another class, generic on it's parameter `T`:*

`CustomClass<T> where T : IMyInterface`

how should this be done?

*(current code won't compile, because `IMyInterface` is dependent on `TParameter, TParameter2`)*.

---

I assume it should be done like:

```
CustomClass<T, TParameter1, TParameter2> where T: IMyInterface<TParameter1,
                                                               TParameter2>
```

but I might be wrong, **could you advice me please?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly as you have it, you need to specify the `TParameter1` and `TParameter2` generic arguments in a class which requires a generic constraint on `IMyInterface`:

```
public interface IMyInterface<TParameter1, TParameter2>
{ 
}

public class CustomClass<T, TParameter1, TParameter2> 
    where T : IMyInterface<TParameter1, TParameter2>
{

}
```

or you could have them fixed:

```
public class CustomClass<T> 
    where T : IMyInterface<string, int>
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to use it as a constraint (with the 'where' keyword)? Here are some examples of straight implementation:

```
interface ITwoTypes<T1, T2>

class TwoTypes<T1, T2> : ITwoTypes<T1, T2>
```

Or, if you know the type(s) your class will use, you don't need a type parameter on the class:

```
class StringAndIntClass : ITwoTypes<int, string>

class StringAndSomething<T> : ITwoTypes<string, T>
```

If you are using the interface as a constraint and don't know the types to specify explicitly, then yes, you need to add the type parameters to the class declaration, as you supposed.

```
class SomethingAndSomethingElse<T, TSomething, TSomethingElse> where T : ITwoTypes<TSomething, TSomethingElse>

class StringAndSomething<T, TSomething> where T : ITwoTypes<string, TSomething>
```